# Using ItemList in an Article and/or NewsArticle

Tags: schema.org

I have a site that offers product recommendations in the form of articles. These product recommendations are broken town in a sort of *Top 5* countdown. Unfortunately it doesn't look ItemLists are accepts as nested values inside an article according to Google's Structuring Data Tool:

[image]

I have to keep the base schema as an Article. With that said, is there still a way to include product lists like I intended to?

Comment: Are you reviewing these products or just listing them with some text?

Comment: Reviewing them within the article.

Comment: Does this help? https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working with multiple products. Is there a way to do that within the link you provided?

Comment: I believe so. Each product review would be marked up within the article. However, I did a quick search for "top ten image editors" in Google and then checked the more popular/successful review sites HTML to see what schema they use. Most did not use review or itemlist. It is important to know that many of these sites are amazon affiliates so the code was the same. One did use itemlist. Paste "view-source:https://www.pcmag.com/roundup/254618/the-best-photo-editing-software" into the address bar to see the code. Perhaps you can check how they use itemlist for clues.

Comment: Okay great. What were they using with the exception of the pcmag link?

Comment: I am confused as to what the best course of action would be for you. Perhaps someone would know for sure. I have not reviewed items on the web so I am weak in this area.

Comment: Oh no I understand. What I'm asking is what schem markup were those sites using that you observed: "However, I did a quick search for "top ten image editors" in Google and then checked the more popular/successful review sites HTML to see what schema they use. Most did not use review or itemlist."

Comment: The pcmag site was using itemlist, however, I did not get deep into how. The code is extensive and I have to leave in a bit.

Comment: All good. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Only one used any markup per item. That was the pcmag site. The others only used schema for website, article, news article, organization, etc. None use markup per item except pcmag.

Comment: Anytime! Cheers mate!!

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks again.